# Can someone explain the error

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
declare
  v_tx varchar2(100);
  type myarray is table of EMP%ROWTYPE;
  rec_a myarray;
begin
  v_tx := 'SELECT * FROM EMP';
  execute immediate v_tx
    into rec_a;
  FOR C in 1 .. rec_a.COUNT
  LOOP
    DBMS_output.put_line(rec_a.ename(C));
  END LOOP;
end;
```

I cant pinpoint the error in it, any help would be very much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Your code has two errors:

- since you're selecting multiple rows into an array, you need BULK COLLECT
- you're using the index variable inside the loop wrong: instead of `rec_a.ename(C)`, you have to use `rec_a(C).ename`

The fixed query is:

```
  declare
      v_tx varchar2(100);
      type myarray is table of EMP%ROWTYPE;
      rec_a myarray;
  begin
      v_tx := 'SELECT * FROM EMP';
      execute immediate v_tx bulk collect
        into rec_a;
      FOR C in 1 .. rec_a.COUNT
      LOOP
        DBMS_output.put_line(rec_a(C).ename);
      END LOOP;
  end;
```